Understanding Invariant $p$-forms
I'm currently reading through Bryant and Salamon's 1989 paper, 'On the construction of some complete metrics with exceptional holonomy', and trying to understand the construction of the subgroups of $G_2$ (and how the associative calibration is invariant under these subgroups), but their construction on p. 831 confuses me.
As a tl;dr for this page, let $V=\Im(\mathbb{H})\oplus\mathbb{H}$; let $\alpha:V\to \Im(\mathbb{H})$ and $\beta:V\to\mathbb{H}$ be projectors (or $\mathbb{H}$-valued 1-forms); and let $B=\bar\beta\wedge\beta/2$. $\{\alpha^1,\alpha^2,\alpha^3,\beta^0,\beta^1,\beta^2,\beta^3\}$ are the 1-form coefficients of the quaternions for $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and form a basis for $V^*$.
Noting that unit quaternions are $SU(2)$ and the double covering of $SO(4)$ is $SU(2)\times SU(2)$, we define the action of $SO(4)$ on $V$ as $[p,q](x,y):=(qx\bar q,py\bar q)$ for $p,q$ unit quaternions. $SO(4)$ then acts on the quaternionic part of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so $[p,q]\alpha = q\alpha\bar q$ and $[p,q]\beta=p \beta \bar q$. $B$ is $\Im(\mathbb{H})$ valued, so transforms as $qB\bar q$.
My confusion arises with their statement that

[t]he $SO(4)$-equivarance of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $B$ shows that the 3-form $\phi=\alpha^1\wedge\alpha^2\wedge\alpha^3 + \alpha^1\wedge B^1 + \alpha^2\wedge B^2 + \alpha^3 \wedge B^3$ is $SO(4)$-invariant.

where $B^1,B^2,B^3$ are the 2-forms multiplying $i,j,k$ resp.
I know how $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $B$ transform under $SO(4)$, but how this shows this 3-form to be invariant I don't know/understand: holistically I can see it, but mathematically I don't understand.
I think this is just me struggling generally with the construction of invariant forms under group transformations, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT
I should maybe be clearer where the calculation confuses me. If we view the action of $SO(4)$ as above, then it only acts on the quaterionic part of the differential form. So then it acts trivially on $\phi$, since it's a real 3-form. This is fine, but it then seems like the entire previous construction was unnecessary. If instead we say that $\alpha^i$ and $B^i$ transform fundamentally, i.e. $\alpha^i\to M^i{}_j\alpha^j$, then the first term in $\phi$ is invariant under $SO(3)< SO(4)$, and we can construct the second term like a Euclidean inner product to show again $SO(3)$ invariance, but I can't see how you show $SO(4)$ from that without also showing $SO(n)$ invariance!
